# Query String Arrays : Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, string, woocommerce

Is it possible to pass an array like this into a query string?

Array:

```
[product_meta] => Array ( [meta_data] => Array ( [cyo_reference] => hello )
```

Query String:

```
cart/?add-to-cart=708&ywcnp_amount=10.16&product_meta[meta_data[cyo_reference]]=hello
```

I need to insert the `hello` word inside `cyo_reference`.

Answer (score 0):

try using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
    e.g 

        $data = array(
            'product_meta' => array(
                'meta_data' => array(
                'cyo_reference'  => 'hello'
            ))

        );


        echo http_build_query($data, '&');  

OutPut :- product_meta%5Bmeta_data%5D%5Bcyo_reference%5D=hello
```

> http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string